# Web LanguageTranslation services (APIs) available out there

Tags: translation

I know there is Google Translate, which some people say is a bit "mechanical" in its translation though it is great.

Can we list the translation web services out there and any pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides a language API to translate text/block of texts.

Using it, you may translate as well as transliterate (in case of Hindi and alike)

> With the AJAX Language API, you can
>   translate and detect the language of
>   blocks of text within a webpage using
>   only Javascript. In addition, you can
>   enable transliteration on any
>   textfield or textarea in your web
>   page. For example, if you were
>   transliterating to Hindi, this API
>   will allow users to phonetically spell
>   out Hindi words using English and have
>   them appear in the Hindi script.

Download Link: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/

Answer (score 0):

Couple of others:

- Microsoft has a machine translation tool called [Bing Translate][1] . This too has an 'auto-detect' for languages but doesn't support all the languages that Google does.
- [BabelFish][2] was popular before Google Translate came along